# Maximum ring volume for one contact, vibrate for others (SMS)

Tags: sms, ringtone, vibration

I keep my phone on vibrate all the day because of my work. So I mostly get back on people when I have the time.

However, I must be informed immediately when some server goes down. For that I have ordered a service which sends me an SMS when it happens.

How would I have the phone ringing with a maximum volume for just one contact, while at the same time have everyone else on vibrate?

Comment: I get a lot of spam - how do I mute rings for all but one contact?

Answer (score 4):

There are SMS apps in the market that allow you to customize notifications by sender.     [Handcent SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) is the one that I've used.